# How can I make in NodeJS Async Buffer

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I search, search and dont find async Buffer.from().
I have for loop and in it Buffer.from(), all its ok, but this Buffer sleep my while, for 100-300 ms, unfortunately this cannot be the case.
Do you have solutions?

// Edit

`await group.getIcon()` - Return Promise Buffer and I need this to base64.

Code like this:

```
try {
    groupIcon = Buffer.from(await group.getIcon()).toString("base64");
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Not found icon");
}
```

Does anyone know the library on npmjs.com, for such things that it happens asynchronously?

Its the function i need to convert to base64. https://multivit4min.github.io/TS3-NodeJS-Library/classes/teamspeakservergroup.html#geticon

Comment: If you need to convert a lot of icons then try to think about worker threads.

Comment: All heavy sync calculations should be removed from the main (and single!) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer is sync. You can modify that buffer a few slice but i wouldn't recommend it if there is no really big buffer. It could be hard to handle and i think that is not a good practice for your problem. I have a better idea and suggestion for speed up your function.

If you haven't got a good reason for wait in loop dont do that.
I dont know what your code doing exactly but as i guess you can modify your code something like below for better performance.

```
let yourFunc = async () => {
  /** Some codes about groups array */
  const groups = await getGroups();
  const iconPromises = [];
  for (let group of groups) {
    try {
      iconPromises.push(group.getIcon());
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Not found icon');
    }
  }
  //Or you can use Promise.allSettled for better error handling
  const icons = await Promise.all(iconPromises);
  const groupIcons = icons.map(icon => Buffer.from(icon).toString('base64'));
  /** then do whatever you want  */
}
```

Comment: I need Buffer in for groups, becouse in for i make updates/insert to mongodb :/